# GROUP BY is not making a distinction, still getting entire result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 8.

I have a message system with a schema, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id             INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    first_name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    --
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (email)
);

CREATE TABLE message (
    id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    to_id   INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    from_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    body    VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    seen    BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    --
    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    --
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (id, to_id, from_id)
);
```

If I have four rows in the `message` table, like this:

```
id, to_id, from_id
------------------
1   1      1     
2   1      1
3   1      1
4   1      2
```

...and then I query the table, then I expect a result set that is a "snapshot" of latest unread messages, with a distinction made on the `to_id`, to look like this:

```
id, to_id, from_id
------------------
3   1      1     
4   1      2
```

However, when I run the query below:

```
SELECT 
    message.id, message.to_id, message.from_id, message.body, message.seen, message.created_at
    `to`.id, `to`.email, `to`.first_name, `to`.last_name
    `from`.id, `from`.email, `from`.first_name, `from`.last_name
FROM message
LEFT JOIN account AS `to`
    ON `to`.id = message.to_id
LEFT JOIN account AS `from`
    ON `from`.id = message.from_id
WHERE message.to_id = 1
    AND message.seen = 0
    AND message.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY message.id, message.to_id, message.from_id
ORDER BY message.created_at DESC
LIMIT 100
```

My result set looks like this:

```
id, to_id, from_id
------------------
1   1      1     
2   1      1
3   1      1
4   1      2
```

It's basically just completely ignoring the `GROUP BY` clause here. I've already spent a lot of time iterating on this, I can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is going on with the account table aliases? That seems overly complicated. See here... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Your query has group by `message.id` which has the definition `id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`. So, the entries in the table based on id will always be unique so grouping by `message.id` will return all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest message for each pair of users, I would start with the correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from message m
where m.id = (select max(m2.id)
              from message m2
              where (m2.to_id = m.to_id and m2.from_id = m.from_id) or
                    (m2.from_id = m.to_id and m2.to_id = m.from_id
            );
```

I'm not sure what the other filtering is for in your query.

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id)
                                order by id desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from message m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Because the table is only referenced once, this makes it easier to bring in other tables and filters.

Comment: The other filtering is for fast pagination, so like `where message.id > 100 limit 100` to page through the table more efficiently than `limit 100 100`. But anyways, that is not relevant to this, so I removed it. Thanks for your suggestion, trying it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as:

```
select max(id) id, max(to_id) to_id, from_id
from...
group by from_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select `distinct message.id, message.to_id, message.from_id`
```